# Why I can't connect 2 players in the same room on a GameCenter turn-based game?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm trying to create a Turn-Based GameCenter multiplayer game and I can't connect 2 players in a match:

I'm connecting with a custom UI and both devices (iPhone and simulator) are running iOS 9.1.

I run on a device and after I run findMatch it creates a new room with me and a player with playerID nil which I read it's normal but when I run on the other device it also does same stuff. Devices are not in same room.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I am using the following code:

```
-(void)searchForTurnBasedMatch{
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
//    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 4;
    request.inviteeResponseHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKInviteeResponse response)
    {
        if (response == GKInviteeResponseAccepted)
        {
            NSLog(@"playerCeva");
        }
    };

    [GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch * _Nullable match, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"eroare la gasire meci: %@",error);
        }
        else if (match != nil)
        {
            self.myTurnBasedMatch = match;
            [self resumeMatch:match];

        }

    }];

}

- (void)resumeMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {
    self.myTurnBasedMatch = match;
    NSLog(@"Created/Selected match");
    NSLog(@"ID: %@\tCreated: %@", match.matchID, match.creationDate);
    GKTurnBasedParticipant *firstParticipant = [match.participants objectAtIndex:0];
    if (firstParticipant.lastTurnDate != NULL) {
        if ([match.currentParticipant.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]) {
            NSLog(@"Taking turn ...");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not my turn ...");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"New game ...");
    }
}
```